# Car share price

Tags: colleagues

I've got a bit tricky situation and would like to get some advice, tips or suggestions. I usually get a lift to work and back with a colleague. Our work is 11miles away. Because we work night shift public transport isn't available unless you sit and wait a couple of hours. Also the bus station is about a 30 min walk. So my colleague gladly offers to give me a lift. At first, it was ok, he was picking me up close to my house and brought me back home if it was raining. But as time went on he started charging more and more also he demanded where I suppose to come and wait that he could pick me up as he doesn't want to go round and about as it's inconvenient. Today he informed me that because petrol prices have gone up he is going to charge £8 per day for giving a lift to work. In my opinion it's a bit too much. What do you think? Is it a reasonable price? What should I do?

---

Probably the best solution would be to save some money and buy a car of my own and get a license rather than being dependent on someone. I did ask him if he wants me to stop going with him and just too shy to tell me. He just asked if someone offered to go cheaper and noted that if I go with another driver and in case I need a lift he won't be taking me as I'm kind of dumping him.

Comment: Buy an electric bike, my sister has just done so for a similar distance and weird work times and she loves it. In fact 3 of her work colleagues have also done the same. But drop him, he is taking the p*ss.

Comment: @SolarMike I doubt buying an e-bike is in the budget of someone working night shifts at places with no public transport. It also does not solve the "when it's raining" problem. Not entirely sure if riding a bike in the middle of a night is safe in such an area.

Comment: That said, it *is* a great idea if you can afford it for sunny days.

Comment: @nvoigt my sister is washing up in a restaurant, the commute is across a city into the sticks where the restaurant is. Making assumptions about budget is interesting, as I can tell you a dishwasher does not get paid much. Maybe budgeting skills could be a more relevant point.

Comment: What do you do when your friend is on holiday?

Answer (score 20):

He's been doing you a favour, and he gets to decide how much (if anything) he wants to charge you. The fact that you're saying he's "demanding" you do things suggests that you don't really see it that way - but that's how it is.

The two main ways that you could try and establish a "fair" price would be:

- Basing the cost on the alternatives (taxi, uber, etc)
- The standard HMRC mileage rate of 45p/mile (which would be £9.90 for 22 miles)

You could *potentially* try and argue that the cost should be based on the difference between his normal commute and the extra miles/time he needs to pick you up (because presumably he would be doing basically the same drive without you) - but arguing with people who are doing you a favour is a good way to get them to stop.

It's also worth considering that perhaps he's increasing the price as a polite way to tell you that he doesn't want to be doing this any more (without just flat-out saying "no" to you).

But ultimately, if you're not happy with how much he wants you to pay, then you are free to say no to him and arrange your own transport to work.

Comment: @EKA, Sorry for your transportation issue. For now, this is the best answer. Maybe, temporarily, you can try to pay him £8 per day while saving enough money to buy a car or to get a better means of transportation in the near future.

Answer (score 12):

Well, find out what a taxi or Uber/Lyft would charge you for the same ride.

Just as an example, when we were still working in the office, I took a colleague in the evening. He literally lived on my route. I took one exit early and dropped him off in a public parking space. That was a ten minute detour. Not driving 10 minutes, just taking the other exit, having two more traffic lights you could sit in front and then dropping them off. That was already the convenience route, bringing them to their front door would take longer.

Now... that is not a lot. If you look at it on a map, you would say "oh come on, that's not a problem". And it's not. Occasionally. But if you do that every day, it's an hour a week. Every week, it's 50 hours a year. That's *one working week*. I literally gifted them the equivalent of one week of vacation directly from my account to theirs. If you had asked me if I wanted to do that, I would certainly have said "hell no!".

Now, I did that because I liked the guy, we had the same hobbies, if he had taken the bus we would have just chatted on the company parking lot for 10 minutes a day after work anyway. But you might not be that friendly with said colleague. I would take the fact that they charge you as evidence of that. And that is not a bad thing. You don't need to be friends with colleagues. A good "working relationship" is plenty.

It is not their job to drive you to and from work. Whether their price is fair, is not really the question. Find alternatives. Then figure out if their price is *worth it*.

Your obvious alternative is getting a car yourself. Or having a job with better transportation options.

Comment: "Your obvious alternative is getting a car yourself." this assumes they have the funds to buy a car, they have a license already or want to get one and they have the capacity, also there are the running costs, taxes, insurance...

Comment: @SolarMike and that is the point. How much will the price be to get a car by your self and is it with it

Comment: @MrZach getting « with it »?

Comment: And is it worth it ;)

Comment: I need license first. Insurance, taxes and patrol I assume would be same what I pay now for a lift. It's just I don't understand about cars and can't afford expensive one. I'm just scared if I buy cheaper one it will need fixing a lot and I can't afford to spend fortune.

Comment: @EKA "Insurance, taxes and patrol I assume would be same what I pay now for a lift." I think you'll pay significantly more than you pay now for your lift. Also don't forget about maintenance. Even if there won't be any problems (which is unlikely if you get a cheaper car) maintenance still isn't free. Add to that the purchase price of the vehicle and that £8 per day isn't such a bad price (it's actually still reasonably cheap for the distance and that's without taking the extra time into account).

Comment: Worth pointing out that your colleague(s) somehow have afford their own transportation.  Personally, I don't think it's unreasonable, to ask another colleague I am picking up and dropping off for some reimbursement. *In fact if I were to car pool, I would make sure, we shared the costs in doing so.*

Answer (score 2):

If a car isn't a possibility atm as you mentioned in your comment, one option would be a bicycle. Depending on your budget either a used/new or electric/non-electric.

I've been riding to and from work since 5 yrs now (32 km round trip), have made about 20.000 km since and my personal experience has showed me the following benifits/insights:

- Personal fitness
- Climate-friendly
- No costs for insurance, road worthy-tests, petrol etc.
- Even possible in winter or during rainfall with proper clothing and tires (for winter)

I decided to get an e-bike because I don't have an oportunity to shower at my workplace and I don't want to attend meetings or come to the office all sweaty. I bought my e-bike 5 years ago for 2700 € and I'm allowed to charge it at work.

Considering the prices for a yearly ticket for public transport for my route, the bike paid for itself after about 3 years and the battery-pack is still up to about 80 % of its initial capacity.

Now considering the charge of 8 pounds with an average of 250 working days (11 public holidays, no PTO in this calculation), which totals at around 2000 pounds a year, the bike would pay for itself within 1.5 years.

If the costs of a new e-bike exceeds your current budget, you can either buy a used e-bike or get a non-electric bicycle (which will be more benificial to your health and fitness than an electrical bike).

Comment: Even ebikes aren't suitable for everyone. One problem is lack of secure storage at the workplace, also there's the condition/safety of roads, and the nature of the job will affect whether you want to spend an hour or more in the saddle every day.

Comment: @StuartF Those are valid points/concerns you are raising - my proposed solution might not work for everyone but will and does for quite a few people around the world ;)

Comment: @StuartF so time on the saddle cf time in the car cf time walking cf time on public transport. Unless you can get a Tardis, all the options take time.